# CodeIgniter 3 'Cannot modify header information' How to get error source

Tags: php, header, codeigniter-3

I am using a multi users application running on a Wamp server 3.1.0. (PHP Version 7.1.22)

Sometimes ,i get this error and i want to know which function or controller is causing this

```
ERROR - 2020-02-26 09:22:56 --> Severity: Warning --> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\wamp64\www\system\libraries\Session\Session_driver.php:49) C:\wamp64\www\system\core\Common.php 570
ERROR - 2020-02-26 09:22:56 --> Severity: Compile Error --> Declaration of SessionHandlerInterface::close() must be compatible with SessionHandlerInterface::destroy($key) C:\wamp64\www\system\libraries\Session\Session_driver.php 49
```

I already changed log_threshold value to 1 to get error log, but i got same result

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 1;
```

Comment: Check any controller you closed using ?> remove that form there then check your log

Comment: what is the line code you are getting error?

Comment: @BoominathanElango i checked all, no ?> in controller

Comment: @ahmednawazbutt i only got 2 lines with no information

Comment: from my experience, if I have some data and I var_dump or print_r it, this warning appears. with echo I dont get any. No idea why